# Proof- division. Is it a true statement or false

Tags: induction, euclidean-algorithm

Prove that $\forall a,b,c,d$ E Z, if $a | c$ and $b | d$ then $(a+b) | (c+d)$

I've got up to here

$$c=ax$$
$$d=by$$
So
$$c+d = ax+by$$

I believe that this a false statement but I don’t know where to go from here

Comment: It is false. Try to find 4 numbers that "do not work".

Comment: If you think it is false in general, find a counterexample.

Comment: If you think the statement is false, it is better to look for a counter-example.

Comment: Here is a simple counterexample, take $a=b=c=1$ and $d=2$

Comment: I think you should prove $$\frac ac=\frac bd\implies \frac ac=\frac{a+b}{c+d}$$ which is true

Comment: If you want to generate more counterexamples, try values where $c+d$ is a prime.